# php ob_flush : How do I make the browser window/page scroll down with the output?

Tags: php, javascript, scroll, flush

Searched a fair bit but couldn't find much about this..

I have a page that is processing quite a few things through a loop, and I have put this at the top of the php page:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();
```

This is happily pumping out the loop to my browser window, but the content is scrolling off the bottom of the page, and I have to keep scrolling down manually. So my question is: **How do I get the page or browser window to scroll with the content?**

I read somewhere using javascript setInterval to start and end scrolling might do the trick, and it sounds like that might be the case - just make the page start scrolling at the beginning of the script and end when it ends.. but I'm not great with javascript yet so was hoping someone could tell me how to do it?

Another solution I can think of is to somehow get javascript to force focus on a particular element class or something as it is being generated.. but this seems like a potentially clunkier option..

Any quick tips would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: only solution is to use java script to keep the window scrolled to the bottom as you already suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add thousands of lines of code, just a short function at the top of your output and a line at the end. This works (add the html at the beginning and /html at the end tags to make it pretty; no need though):

```
<script>
var scroller = setInterval(function() {  
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}, 10); // update every 10 ms, change at will
</script>
<?php
// generate 1000 lines of html code
for($i=0; $i<1000; $i++){
    echo $i . "<br>";
    ob_flush(); // flush out the output as we go
    flush(); // same
    usleep(10000); // add some delay to see it in action  
}

?>

<script>
clearInterval(scroller); // stop updating so that you can scroll up 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this javascript:

```
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}

document.documentElement.scrollTop = getDocHeight();
```

you can simply add the line

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = getDocHeight();
```

to every piece you send to the client in order to update the scrollbar...

or

add this line of code to the beginning of your output:

```
var scroller = setInterval(function() {  
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = getDocHeight();
}, 100 /*update intervall in ms*/);
```

and this line to the end of your output:

```
clearInterval(scroller);
```

Comment: Ok thank you, that works. But do you think this is the best solution? Is there anything I can do which will not add thousands of extra lines to my output? It would be nice to be able to make some javascript call which starts scrolling at the beginning of the loop and ends at the end...

Comment: Great! That works too and I still have tidy code. I guess I'm not sure what the UI effects will be on other machines but it seems smooth and functional for me. Thank you for your time!